# Spring MVC. Где и как проверить авторизацию пользователя?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Каким образом лучше проверить авторизацию пользователя и где это найти? При каждом заходе на страницу и при каждом `REST` запросе. Создать `Filter`?

P.S. `Spring Security` не предлагайте, ибо я в этом еще не разобрался...

Comment: Если на чистых сервлетах я делаю фильтр то как можно тут? так же само?

Comment: Почему не предлагать Spring Security, если это реально правильное решение? Почему сразу не начинать разбираться в том, что правильно?

Comment: @RomanDanilov ибо сначала нужно разобраться в базовом спринге и спринг  mvc, а потом уже лезть в глубины... Иначе будет каша в голове.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вам нужен фильтр.

В фильтре вам надо проверить части запроса на предмет наличия данных об авторизации. Это может быть токен или кука (т.е. просто строка с к-л текстом) в параметре или заголовке. Эту строку вам надо проверить на соответствие с информацией хранящейся на сервере. Например наличие этой строки в таблице БД, в которой хранятся данные о залогиненных юзерах.

В случае, если такая строка найдена и найдено соответствие в БД вы можете из БД вытащить объект юзера, прикрепить его к запросу и пропустить его дальше. Иначе - выкинуть 403 ошибку.

Comment: Сама реализация проверки есть, но на чистых сервлетах. Мне еще главное понять как это передать в контроллер. подскажете?

Comment: @Tsyklop, единственное, чем могу помочь - дать ссылку на коммит где я фильтр свой делал. Но там есть security и вообще там сложно: https://github.com/mohaxspb/springSecurityExample/commit/4cf4df36c041c425131e30b87ed4fc340f092e06

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я решил данную проблему

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override public void init(FilterConfig config) {}
    @Override public void destroy() {}
    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
                                   ServletResponse res,
                                   FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login";
        String registrURL = request.getContextPath() + "/registr";

        boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL) || request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL + ".html");
        boolean registrRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(registrURL) || request.getRequestURI().equals(registrURL + ".html");

        if(loggedIn || loginRequest || registrRequest) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
        }
    }
}
```

В web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**P.S.** За основу брал [данный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/authentication-filter-and-servlet-for-login) BalusC. Он объяснил некоторые важные моменты.